# how to know the state of a response with fetch Api javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

```
function boleta(){
    var check = false;
    var formboleta = new FormData();
    formboleta.append("num_boleta", data2.boletas[id].num_boleta);
    formboleta.append("created_at", data2.boletas[id].created_at);
    formboleta.append("total", data2.boletas[id].total);
    //arreglo id productos
    for(let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
        formboleta.append("productos", data2.boletas[id].productos[k].id);
    }
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formboleta,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    let status;
    fetch("url_goes_here", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      status = response.status;
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    //---------------------------------------------
}
```

Hi guys, i want to know how to get the state of a response, to make an if and execute another function if the state is 200 or success.

in the first response i want to make if status is ok, call another function
which in this case it will be function cliente();.

The function cliente(); will do another post and create a customer for this ticket, but i can't call it when the ticket( by ticket i mean the function boleta, which inside creates a boleta(ticket)) isn't done already.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: i did what decpk said and got this error  Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.', i'll update the code

Comment: In your posted code there's a misplaced `)`

Comment: include the error... It seems you already have the response in the variable status so you can just check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the status of an HTTP request as

```
.then((response) => {
    status = response.status;
    return response.json();
  })
```

If you somehow want status in second `then`, then create a variable and store the status after getting the response like

```js
let status;
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then((response) => {
    // Get status using response.status
    status = response.status;
    console.log(`status in first then ${status}`);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json) => {
    // Get status in after the first .then
    console.log(`status in second then 4 ${status}`);
    console.log(console.log(json));
  });
```